# Can't import Python module from paralell dir, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

can't import module

[image: can't import module]

This works in pycharm, but not in VS Code...

Why can't I import "constants_and_helpers"?

Comment: from the point of view of `transformer.py` `constants_and_helpers` is not a subdir/sibling of the module and it is also not in the `sys.path`. Most likely PyCharm assumes the workspace folder is the start/current directory when running

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have settings in pychar that allow you to use the workspace as a runtime folder.

In VsCode, you can create `.env` file under the workspace. Then add the setting to your `settings.json` under `.vscode` folder:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

In .env file, you can add your workspace to PYTHONPATH:

```
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/YOUR/WORKSPACE
```

Then you can use **DEBUG** mode or **interactive window**.